# Device driver without the device?

Tags: windows, kernel, kernel-module

I'm creating an application that needs to use some kernel level modules, for which I've divided the app into 2: one user-level program and one kernel level program.

After reading about device drivers and walking through some tutorials, I'm a little confused.

Can there be a device driver without any specific device associated with it? Is there anything other than the device driver (kernel code or something) which works in kernel mode?

How do anti-virus programs and other such applications work in kernel mode? Is device driver the correct way or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, device drivers can work without an actual piece of hardware (i.e. the device) attached to the machine. Just think of the different programs that emulate a connected SCSI drive (CD-ROM, whatever) for mounting ISO images. Or think about TrueCrypt, which emulates (removable) drives using containers, which are nothing more than encrypted files on your hard drive.

A word of warning, though: Driver development requires much more thought and has to be done more carefully, no shortcuts, good testing and in general expects you to know quite a good deal about the Windows driver model. Remember that faulty and poor drivers put the whole system's stability in jeopardy.

Honestly, I don't think reading a tutorial is sufficient here. You might want to *at least* invest in a decent book on that subject. Just my 2 cents, though.

Comment: Thanks, that gave me some clarity. I had ordered the book Microsoft System Internals, was just doing a little homework till it arrived.

Comment: there is ambiguity in the term "device" when it comes to Windows kernel drivers. Almost any driver I've seen, except some malware, has at least a CDO. And a CDO is of the kernel object type "Device". Check it out, if you don't believe me :)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but the Windows Internals book is more of a general reading for the curious. I cannot recommend it if you want to engage in driver development - or at most as prerequisite reading to understand the architecture. There are plenty of other books around, although most of them are a bit older.

Depending on your goal, you may get away with one of the simpler driver models. That is not to say that driver development is trivial - in fact I second all aspects of the warning above and would even go further - but it means that you can save some of the more tedious work, if instead of writing a legacy file system filter you'd write one based on the filter manager. However, Windows XP before SP2 did not have it installed by default and Windows 2000 would require SP4+SRP+patch if I remember correctly. WDF (Windows Driver Foundation) makes writing drivers even easier, but it is not suitable for all needs.

The term device is somewhat of bad choice here. Device has a meaning in drivers as well, and it does not necessarily refer to the hardware device (as pointed out). Roughly there is a distinction between PDOs (physical device objects) and CDOs (control device objects). The latter are usually what you get to see in user mode and what can be accessed by means of CreateFile, ReadFile, WriteFile, DeviceIoControl and friends. CDOs are usually made visible to the Win32 realm by means of symbolic links (not to be confused with the file system entities of the same name). Drive letter assignments like C: are actually symbolic links to an underlying device. It depends on the driver whether that'd be a CDO or PDO. The distinction is more of a conceptual one taught as such in classes.

And that's what I would actually recommend. Take a class about Windows driver development. Having attended two seminars from OSR myself, I can highly recommend it. Those folks know what they're talking about. Oh, and sign up to their mailing lists over at OSR Online.

Use Sysinternals' WinObj to find out more about the device and driver objects and symlinks.

---

As for the question about AVs, yes they use file system filter drivers (briefly mentioned above). The only alternative to a full-fledged legacy FSFD is a mini-filter.

It is possible to load a special kind of DLL in kernel mode, too. But in general a driver is the way into the kernel mode and well documented as such.

Books you may want to consider (by ISBN): Most importantly "Programming the Windows Driver Model" (0735618038), "Windows NT Device Driver Development" (1578700582), "Windows NT File System Internals" (0976717514 (OSR's new edition)), "Undocumented Windows NT" (0764545698) and "Undocumented Windows 2000 Secrets" (0201721872) - and of course "Windows NT/2000 Native API Reference" (9781578701995) (classic). Although the last three more or less give you a better insight and are not strictly needed as reading for driver developers.

Answer (score 1):

Anti-virus (and system recovery) software generally make use of file-system filter drivers. A device can have multiple filter drivers arranged like a stack, and any event/operation on this device has to pass through all the stacked up drivers. For example, anti-viruses install a filter driver for disk device so that they can intercept and scan all file system (read/write) operation.

As mentioned in above post, going through a good book would be a nice way to start. Also, install DDK/WDK and refer the bundled examples.