# install driver for a missing device

Tags: c++, device-driver

I have a device driver for a PC/104 sensor.  I'd like to start developing code (a) before the device arrives, and (b) on a machine to which the device will not attach.  I have the driver "disk" (actually, a .zip file).

My operating system is Windows 7 Professional; target operating system is Windows 7 Embedded or Windows XP Embedded.  (The SBC hasn't arrived yet, either.)

I found a question from someone who wanted to write a device driver before the device was constructed ([Device driver without the device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750282/device-driver-without-the-device)), but here I have a commercial device driver and want to install (at least) the .dll and .h file before the device arrives.

The IDE on this machine is C++builder; I have no idea what the IDE will be on the target machine

Comment: What's preventing you from installing the driver exactly?

Comment: Many installers refuse to install if there isn't a "device" that matches the driver that it's installing. However, to install the SDK (the header files, libraries etc) should definitely be possible. Read the instructions for the board to find out how - since it's quite unlikely you'll find the same instructions for two diferent types of PC/104 sensor implementations, no one here can even guess what you need to do without you at least telling WHAT the sensor is.

Comment: AFAIK, this is what DriverPackagePreinstall function does.

Comment: It's a WinSystems PCM-ADIO board.  The instructions are to use the Windows XP "Add Hardware" tag, after attaching the device (which is absolutely **not** P-n-P).  I called the sales staff (which has been closed for about a hour now for the holidays), and they called their technical support, which reported "follow the instructions, as the device will not be detected by Windows _until_ the driver is installed."

Comment: To Mat:  I don't know what's preventing me.  I've rarely installed sofware except by following OS or manufacturer's instructions before, and this time, both tell me to wait until the device is attached.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably two parts to what you need to do:-

a : Install Windows drivers so that the operating system recognises the device. This you can't usefully do without the device actually connected. However, I'm not sure if your device actually needs this, or if you event have a true Windows "device driver"

b: Install the "SDK" for the device so that you can start writing code. The ".h" file is a C or C++ header file that you'll need to `#include` in any program you write. Typically you just place this somehwere in the include search path. You'll also probably have a DLL which you must ship with your program executable that either talks to the device directly or via the driver installed in a: above.

You will also need to make a library file for C++ builder to allow you to 'link' to the DLL. C++Builder has an `IMPLIB` command-line tool for this purpose, and  .lib files built for Visual Studio are not directly compatible.

Comment: The .h file works properly; I'm still having trouble with the .lib file, but IMPDEF shows that the mangled names are not being mangled correctly, so I'm going to have to _edit_ the .lib file to get it to work.  Thanks, anyway.